# QT: Statically linked library not found

Tags: qt

Following and reading "Application Development with QT Creator" chapter 2 making a static lib math function. Anyhow I follow along and after selecting the library I created QT can't include the math function as if its not found! Says dependent not found!

```
:-1: error: dependent 'C:\Users\david\Desktop\QT_exper\MathTest\..\MathFunctions\debug\MathFunctions.lib' does not exist.
```

Must be a path issue in the PRO file?

Comment: can you please share your .pro file corresponds to the library includes?

Comment: Sorry I altered the path and removed the '..' because apparently Windows can't parse that and copied my library files into the test console app folder. So now it compiles but having issues with QT recognizing and autocomplete typing the function.h file that I compiled into 'lib' file. Not only that when I compile the library I get an 'Executable not found' dialogue that pops up. So not sure if I am doing this right. Here is my current 'fixed' pro file for the lib:

Comment: Edit: Stackoverflow says that the text is too long to include.